# useEffect with only one dependency / React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props'

Tags: reactjs, eslint, use-effect, use-state

I want to be able to reuse my input form as an edit form, so in the form component I check if there is an **id** in the url with { useParams }, and if there is, set state of the input fields with the data i get from a function **getContact** that is passed down with props.

In UseEffect I want to track **id** but not **props**, so I just put **[id]** as a dependency at the end of useEffect. If I add **[id, props]** I'm not able to set the state of the input fields because it instantly sets it back to the values i get back from **getContact()** (since there IS an **id** if I'm editing).

I'm very new to React so I just wonder if there is a better way to do this, or if I should just put **// eslint-disable-next-line** in my code and get on with my life :-)

```
    const Form = (props) => {
      const { id } = useParams();
    
      const [input, setInput] = useState({});
    
      useEffect(() => {
        setInput(id ? props.getContact(id) : {});
      }, [id]);
    
      const handleChange = (event) => {
        let value = event.target.value;
        let name = event.target.name;
    
        setInput((prev) => {
          return { ...prev, [name]: value };
        });
      };

... A few more functions and then a return that spits out som JSX
```

Comment: You must remember that the moment you change the id on the url, the component re-renders... this is based on Router. So this mean you can’t achieve value tracking of id within a component internally. That component will rerender on every id changed

Comment: I am also not sure why you want to track The value of is if its changed or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that is used within the useEffect should be added to the dependency array. Why not extract the id you want to set instead like this?

```
const contectId = id ? props.getContact(id) : {};
useEffect(() => {
    setInput(contectId);
  }, [contectId]);
```

This only works if you store the {} somewhere where it does not change on render:
Either like this:

```
const emptyArray = React.useMemo(() => {}, [])
const contectId = id ? props.getContact(id) : emptyArray;
useEffect(() => {
    setInput(contectId);
  }, [contectId]);
```

or

```
const emtyArray = {};
const Form = (props) => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  const [input, setInput] = useState({});

 const contectId = id ? props.getContact(id) : emtyArray;
  useEffect(() => {
    setInput(contectId);
  }, [contectId]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    let value = event.target.value;
    let name = event.target.name;

    setInput((prev) => {
      return { ...prev, [name]: value };
    });
    console.log(input);
   };
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried your solution but it didn't work, the error was gone but the behaviour vas the same as when i added props as a dependency in useEffect, I couldn't edit because the input-field-values was immediately set back to the initial values...

Comment: What does getContactId do?

Comment: OH MAN, SORRY, this totally worked, I had another bug in another place that kept loading the data over and over that messed everything up. Thank you SO MUCH! One thing though, I don't understand why I need an empty object outside of form, i tried it with just const contectId = id ? props.getContact(id) : {}; and it worked just fine :-D

Comment: Great, could you accept the answer then so other can find this answer. Because react checks for shallow comparison, so if the object reference changes, it gets triggered. And with the previous code, you create a new object on every render and that would trigger it on every render, because the reference to the object changed,

Comment: Sorry again, I see now why I need the empty object outside the Form, at least I think so. Otherwise I can't use the blank form to add a new contact. Im very new to this, so thank you SO much, this was super helpful!